# LVM + how to remove physical volume

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, lvm

from `lsblk` we have the following:

```
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0 372.6G  0 disk
├─sda1               8:1    0   500M  0 part  /boot
└─sda2               8:2    0 372.1G  0 part
  ├─vger-root      253:0    0    50G  0 lvm   /
  ├─vger-swap      253:1    0     4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
  └─vger-lv_var    253:2    0 318.1G  0 lvm   /var
.
.
.

sdr                 65:16   0 372.6G  0 disk
├─sdr1              65:17   0   512M  0 part
└─sdr2              65:18   0 372.1G  0 part
  └─qw127            9:127  0   372G  0 raid1
    ├─vger-lv_swap 253:3    0    16G  0 lvm
    └─vger-lv_root 253:4    0   100G  0 lvm
```

this below configuration defined the raid1 mirror software raid1

and from `pvs` we have the following

```
 PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/qw127 vger lvm2 a--  371.98g 155.98g
  /dev/sda2  vger lvm2 a--  372.12g  60.00m
```

is it possible to remove the `PV` -   `/dev/qw127 vger lvm2 a--  371.98g 155.98g`  ?

so we get only this from `pvs`

```
 PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  vger lvm2 a--  372.12g  60.00m
```

when we do:

```
 pvmove /dev/qw127
  Physical Volume "/dev/qw127" not found in Volume Group "vger"

vgreduce vger /dev/qw127
  Failed to find physical volume "/dev/qw127".
```

we get the above failed

***also another info***

```
lsblk -f
NAME               FSTYPE            LABEL       UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda
├─sda1             xfs                           a3f49684-6ade-485f-97e4-b16716005d1e   /boot
└─sda2             LVM2_member                   Gf7aES-gf1y-6bcu-BQz7-52Iw-tCYo-eyWwtw
  ├─vger-root      xfs                           989f89fb-66f9-40ee-90d7-a289623e0061   /
  ├─vger-swap      swap                          ac93e301-3a3a-4619-bdd3-f3c571583ebf   [SWAP]
  └─vger-lv_var    xfs                           4d73cf49-5f7b-4bdb-b066-fefd18eccdf3   /var
sdb                ext4                          bf0f6ca9-747f-4cab-9c54-73e017857834   /data/sdb

sdr
├─sdr1             xfs                           de6d3f14-f930-4b61-9967-23fed3e7decf
└─sdr2             linux_raid_member localhost:1 8d206129-1807-9d30-442a-9630779bc629
  └─qw127          LVM2_member                   ADFzSV-qNns-qSTX-DGMo-OUCN-IZ4g-zCwOAi
    ├─vger-lv_swap swap                          565a0460-abcd-4822-909f-dd82d76cd233
    └─vger-lv_root xfs
```

Comment: You can remove it as long as you have accounted for any data that's on it. Have you attempted to do any of this?

Comment: In response to your updates, the file system on your logical volumes is `xfs` so you can't resize them. As the logical volumes using the physical volume of `qw127` aren't mounted anywhere, that would indicate that they aren't being used. It's up to you to determine if `vger-lv_root` has data on it so that you can back it up before you proceed.

Comment: Similar question with identical `lsblk` output asked by different user at https://serverfault.com/questions/1062312/linux-how-to-disable-software-raid1.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't remove the PV, because you don't have enough free space in the VG -- `/dev/qw127` is ~372 GiB and you have only ~216 GiB of free space, so you first need to make sure you at least 372 GiB of free space in `vger` by resizing/removing existing LVs. After that you can use `pvmove /dev/qw127` to move all the LVs from this PV to the other one and after that you can remove the PV using `vgreduce vger /dev/qw127`.

Comment: Depending on what the filesystem is, he may not be able to resize the LVs. XFS LVs can't be resized. Whether that's the case or not, he can remove it if the data is backed up as he'd just have to recreate the volume group and logical volume and then restore it.

Comment: see the update - when I do vgreduce vger /dev/qw127  , we get 
  Failed to find physical volume "/dev/qw127".

Comment: @yael Add the output of `lsblk -f` to your question so that the filesystem is known to determine if you can even resize the logical volumes.

Comment: see the update in "also another info"